# TCPReplay 3.4.4: Unable to find libpcap in /usr

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, pcap

I'm having a problem installing TCPReplay 3.4.4 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I'm getting this error when I run `configure`

`checking for libpcap... configure: error: Unable to find libpcap in /usr`

I have `libpcap0.8 (1.1.1)` installed.

Thanks.

Edit: I've searched everywhere for an answers but I couldn't find a definite answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, the most likely cause is that you don't have the libpcap development headers installed.  Any time you compile an application which requires a library, you always need to have the headers installed as well.  But default installs don't install the headers since they just take up extra disk space for most users.

Comment: I've installed `libpcap-dev` and I'm still having that error. Installing the dev was the first thing that I did when I saw that error.